# Changing buffer size for certain amount of seconds

Tags: c++, audio, signal-processing

My question is that, given a buffer of int16_t buffer[128]; used to sample and play back an audio signal at 48kHz=Fs, how would I change the buffer size such that the buffers only store 0.25s of data.

Here's what I think, but I have no way of proving it given my hardware experience:

- I have 48000 samples/second if I'm sampling at 48kHz.  Therefore, to get only 1/4 of a second (12000 samples?) my buffer size would be int16_t buffer[32]

I'm not that knowledgeable about hardware, so any guidance/direction or help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: To store a whole 0.25s worth of data at 48kHz in a buffer, you would need a buffer of 12000 samples. If you had a buffer of 128 samples, then you were only buffering at most ~2.7ms worth of data at a time (which doesn't mean you can't process more than 2.7ms of audio, you just have to do the processing in small chunks).

Answer (score 1):

```
floor(25*48000/100)

ans =

       12000
```

So do you need `int16_t buffer[12000]` to get 0.25s of audio.

if you are doing something in real time a buffer of this size can cause undesired latency.

Comment: true for mono - double if Jim needs stereo

Comment: perfectly well remembered